# Small code, big test

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have this code in a controller of an MVC implementation:

```
public void execute() {
        try {
            String path = userSelectsFile(); 
            if ( path == null ) return; //Just returns if the user press "Cancel"

            //Load the data
            Collection<Info> infos = Infos.fromJSON(getInputReader(path));
            //Show the data in the interface
            new ShowTransformationsInTree(win(), infos, win().getTree()).execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new ComplainAction(win(), "Unable to...blah, blah", e).execute();
        }
    }
```

To test this, I have to mock the user interface to show file dialog and make `getInputReader` method an abstract factory method.

#### Test code:

```
    /**
     * Mocks the LoadTransformationsAction so the factory method getReader returns a ByteInputStream
     */
    public class MockLoadTransformationsAction extends LoadTransformationsAction {
        //CONSTRUCTOR REMOVED FOR CLARITY.....

        @Override
        protected InputStreamReader getInputReader(String path) {
            assertEquals(FAKE_ABSOLUTE_PATH, path);
            return new InputStreamReader(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(TestHelpers.createDataBytes());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Test the proper loading of the data.
     */
    @Test
    public void testLoadData(@Mocked final FileChooser anyChooser) {
        new Expectations() {{
            //Mocks the IntelliJ idea API
            FileChooser.chooseFile(null, null, null); result = new MyFakeVirtualFile(); //Returns a fixed path
        }};

        //Loads the data from the JSON file
        MainToolWin m = new FakeMainToolWin();
        LoadTransformationsAction action = new MockLoadTransformationsAction(
                m, new FakeProject(), new MockInputProgram());
        action.execute();

        //Test that the transformations are in the UI Tree
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)m.getTree().getModel();
        assertEquals(2, model.getChildCount(model.getRoot()));
        assertEquals(3, model.getChildCount(model.getChild(model.getRoot(), 0)));
    }
```

#### Questions:

Am I doing too much to test too little?

As you can see there are mock and fake objects all the way. Can so much mocking can make my test unreliable?

Is there a better design?

Comment: Maybe this is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . At first glance, I'd say that you just hit the typical "void" problem. Since the whole method is essentially side-effect only, it's always going to be way harder to test than pure functions.

Comment: @Frank, Thanks, there are so many stackexchanges that is hard to know where to ask :D. Regarding the "void", this gives me a research direction!

Comment: I think this question belongs here, because it has to do with methodology, not with code.  The question is valid regardless of language and irrespective of the specific problem at hand.

Comment: I agree with @Frank. Any code that consists purely of interactions with the "outside world" can't be reliably tested; you'll have to create a model of the outside world, and that model will duplicate the same assumptions you made in the code being tested. Besides, unit tests are useful because they're trivial enough to be verified by inspection; if it's easier to inspect the correctness of the code being tested, the test is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, too many or too complicated mock objects are a bad thing.  Yes, there is a better design, and I have been toying with the idea in my mind for years. Unfortunately, I cannot fully explain it here because the paper that I am writing about it is not complete yet.  But, in coarse terms, here is what is happening:

You are mixing business logic with GUI logic, and GUIs are generally very hard to test. You are already making some effort to separate the two, as evidenced by your use of a (presumably GUI-agnostic) tree model data structure, but you are not going all the way with this idea, since you are only making this tree available to your business logic via a "main tool window" which is a GUI concept.

The notion of presenting the user with the opportunity to select a file, which they may cancel, is part of your business logic.  The fact that you use a GUI to accomplish this is irrelevant: you could achieve the same thing with a command-line interface, asking the user to *type* the filename, and allowing for an empty filename to mean 'cancel'.

So, if you completely isolated all your business logic from the GUI-related code, then your business logic would be fully testable with no mock objects.  (Not just a few simple mock objects, but actually *zero* mock objects.)

Generally, the presence of a mock object in testing means that the design is not perfect.  Quite often an imperfect design which requires mock objects to test is a pragmatic compromise, but you seem to be asking what's best, so, that's what's best.

EDIT:

After discussing it a bit, it turns out that your main concern is the accessing of the data in the file. Here is what I have to say about this:

(And yes, now it seems like this question is more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com.)

Currently, your business logic needs some "Infos" to work with, but it contains specific hard-coded knowledge of the fact that these "Infos" are coming from JSON; furthermore, it contains specific hard-coded knowledge of the fact that this JSON comes from a file.  (By virtue of the 'path' variable.) I think that's a bit problematic.  If your business logic needs some "Infos" to work with, it should not be concerned with how they can be obtained.  It should just be given those infos from the outside.  So, instead of having to mock the creation of a stream, your test code would just be constructing test instances of the "Infos" class to test your business logic with.

Then, you would need a separate set of tests to make sure that your Infos.fromJSON() method works correctly, and these tests would belong to the "Infos" class, not to your controller class.  (Maybe you already have them.)

Essentially, what you would be doing with such an approach is that you would be isolating your business logic from the file system, and from text-file-format-choice (JSON) considerations, which is just as crucial as isolating it from the GUI.

If you don't want to do all this, then you have to create precisely that mock object which you have created; this should not come as a surprise, and it is actually not an awful lot of work compared to what you need to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for Ur answer. At the moment it does not convince me, thou I must admit is because I’m failing to understand some concepts. I will study it thoroughly nevertheless. Thanks again.

Comment: "You are mixing business logic with GUI logic"

I don't think that's the problem since: is not that what is supposed to do the controller of the MVC? I'm no expert please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, using MVC will not automatically isolate your GUI from your business logic, just as using the `class` keyword does not automatically guarantee that you are doing object-oriented programming. I am not sure what the state of the art is with respect to MVC, (perhaps wait for another answer?) but in my book, if your business logic is `using` any GUI namespaces then it is not isolated from the GUI.

Comment: Indeed separating GUI from logic is a good idea. The problem is that in this specific case, all mocking is to access the data in the file (As you can see from the mock to the input stream an File chooser). No mocking is done because of the UI. That's why I believe in this particular case the separation is not the solution. 

Let's suppose I do separation. I still have to test the code that loads the file. In this case is almost pure external API calls. My question is more how to test almos pure calls to API. Thanks Mike for your patience.

Comment: I see.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.  No problem, we are here to help.  I amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try writing tests first and then write implementation. By doing this way you'll see that your tests will be short and simple and the implementation as well.
2. Use as many simple interfaces as you can.
3. In your method 'execute' I don't see any story. If I would do such kind of thing I would have such implementations:

   - An object that returns selected path
   - An object that validates path
   - An object that parses file specified in the path

String path = pathProvider.provideSelectedPath()
pathValidator.validate(path)
UseData data = infoReader.readFromPath(path)
return data

If user pressed cancel -- it's GUI logic
Show user data -- it's GUI logic

Comment: that will solve the problem of how to test the code at hand, it also proposes a better desing. Thanks. However the following questions remain:
1. Am I doing too much to test too little?
2.Can so much mocking can make my test unreliable?

Comment: 1. Am I doing too much to test too little?
Taking into consideration your solution I´m still with the same problem of writing more code for test than for production. Making test harder than production, reducing the value of the later.

2.) As you can see there are mock and fake objects all the way. Can so much mocking can make my test unreliable?
Making 3 interfaces to test the call of 3 API objects isn´t that  basically a way of mocking? So again: Can so much mocking can make my test unreliable? Thanks for ur time :)

Comment: Never hesitate to write unit tests. It is the core of the tests (refer to the test pyramid). If it is difficult to write unit tests -- think about design of your system, it might be bad, since difficult setup of the tests is the sign of it.

Comment: Mocks should be used to hide outer dependencies. If you think, that these tests are unreliable, add functional tests, integration tests.